# How to delete directory from path in terminal?

Tags: shell, command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

If I'm using the terminal to do something like:

`cd ~/ex/exFolder2/IWantToDeleteThis`

How do I delete the `IWantToDeleteThis` part on Mac?

I've tried **Ctr+W** but that deletes the whole path up to `cd`.

Comment: `Esc + Backspace` together does that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the default settings for bash, Meta-Rubout does it here (which is Esc-Backspace on my FreeBSD system). From the bash manual:

```
    backward-kill-word (M-Rubout)
          Kill  the  word  behind  point.  Word boundaries are the same as
          those used by backward-word.
```

If you are not afraid to rewire your brain for command line editing, try **vi mode** with `set -o vi`. Then you can do fancy things like

```
ESC dF/     # Delete back finding /
ESC d2F/    # Delete back across 2 /
```

The possibilities are endless.